# CSS;- Radio buttons with circles having very less spacing between them

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make circles without spacing which should behave like a radio buttons. I was able to do that but I was not able to remove the spacing between the radio buttons. Margin between two circles should be 1 px, not more than that. Also, width, height should not be more than 8px, in other words I want small circles.

Here is the code

```
<input type='radio' name='a' checked/>
<input type='radio' name='a'/>


input[type='radio'] {
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    width:8px;
    height:8px;
    border:1px solid darkgray;
    border-radius:50%;
    outline:none;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px gray inset;
}
input[type='radio']:hover {
    box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px orange inset;
}
input[type='radio']:before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    /*margin: 20% auto;    */
    border-radius:50%;    
}
input[type='radio']:checked:before {
    background:green;
}

input[type='radio']:before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    /*margin: 20% auto;    */
    border-radius:50%;    
}
```

Comment: Please share the link of `jsfiddle`.

Comment: Not clear on the visual effect you are going for. If you just add `margin: 0` to your `input[type="radio"]` css, the radio buttons will get much closer together but not sure how close you want them to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the margin from the radio buttons and set 1px to the right, also by removing the white space between the two inputs you remove additional space.

```css
input[type='radio'] {
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    width:8px;
    height:8px;
    border:1px solid darkgray;
    border-radius:50%;
    outline:none;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px gray inset;
    margin: 0 1px 0 0;
}
input[type='radio']:hover {
    box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px orange inset;
}
input[type='radio']:before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    /*margin: 20% auto;    */
    border-radius:50%;    
}
input[type='radio']:checked:before {
    background:green;
}

input[type='radio']:before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    /*margin: 20% auto;    */
    border-radius:50%;    
}
```

```html
<input type='radio' name='a' checked/><input type='radio' name='a'/>
```